# Can you manually convert between std::string and std::wstring

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I'm using the new C++ `<filesystem>` library, and all the strings representing file and folder names are returned as `const wchar_t*` pointers. In my program, I use `char`s and `std::string`, which is fine as far as I know because all file paths can be written with `ASCII` characters *(only one byte)*. There is a way to convert from `std::wstring` to `std::string`, but the `<codecvt>` header that's used for this is deprecated after C++17.

I was wondering, what would be the harm in simply just reading the value of each 2-byte `wchar_t` into a single-byte `char`? Whenever you have to convert from `std::wstring` *(I'm assuming `UTF-16`)* to single-byte `std::string`, any characters greater than `127` or `255` in the `std::wstring` can't be contained in the `char`, so they can't be converted in any way, right?

Comment: what about https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string

Comment: `char` strings can use multi-char sequences to represent values that do not fit into a single `char`. Also you should read [this](http://utf8everywhere.org)

Comment: _"all filepaths can be written with ASCII characters (only one byte)"_ Who says?

Comment: _"any characters greater than 127 or 255 in the std::wstring can't be contained in the char, so they can't be converted in any way, right?"_ Sounds like you need to do some more reading on string encodings!!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings You can store a character with a value of more than 255 in one byte? Also which characters in a filepath aren't covered by ASCII?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: @Zebrafish "*You can store a character with a value of more than 255 in one byte?*" - there are single-byte character encodings, like Windows-125x, ISO-5589-x, etc that have single-byte *representations* of Unicode characters higher than 127. For example, byte `0x80` in Windows-1252 represents Unicode character U+20AC. There are many multi-byte character encodings available (UTFs, Shift-JIS, etc). These are commonly referred to as *charsets*, which are implemented as *code pages* on Windows.

Comment: @Zebrafish "*Also which characters in a filepath aren't covered by ASCII?*" - standard ASCII covers only Unicode characters U+0000..U+007F in bytes `0x00..0x7F` (0..127). But, there are "Extended ASCII" encodings that can cover higher Unicode characters in bytes `0x80-0xFF`, but these are non-standardized.  And then there are the single-byte encodings, which are commonly referred to as "ANSI" encodings, though they are not really part of ANSI itself (which is its own standard).

Comment: @Zebrafish Have a look at [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).